# Combine inverse property and inverse class selector with existing selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have this jQuery code:

```
$("#Filter ul input:checked").each(function () {
    if (!$(this).prop("disabled") && !$(this).hasClass("ignoreInput")) {
```

Can this be written in only one selector? Right now I'm taking in too many elements to test with the `if` statement.

Is it also better to use `.find(selector)` instead of writing all in one selector?

```
$(document.body).find("#Filter ul ...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of `:not()` along with the attribute selector, like this:

```
$("#Filter ul input:checked:not([disabled],.ignoreInput)").each(function () {
    // your logic here
});
```

> Is it also better to use .find(selector) instead of writing all in one selector?

This makes little to no performance difference.

Comment: could you explain the squere brackets syntax of disabled?

Comment: @juFo That's the synthax for attribute selector

Comment: @juFo It's all in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Comment: so this code: 
$("[class*='slider-range-']").each(function () { if (!$(this).prop("disabled")) {    
would translate to: 
$("[class*='slider-range-']:not([disabled])")